# Mulitvariate normal truncated conditional expectation

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, mean, conditional-expectation

There is three-variable multivariate normal distribution. Denote 3 variables with $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$. Let $\mu_i$ be means, and $\sigma_i^2$ variances of respective variables, and let $\Sigma$ be covariance matrix. 
Can someone help me with deriving expressions for:

$$E(X_1|X_2>a,X_3>b)$$ and $${\rm Var}(X_1|X_2>a, X_3>b)$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are some real numbers.

Comment: The trivariate case is messy. See the paper by: Tallis (1961), The moment generating function of the truncated multinormal distribution. _Journal of the Royal Statistical Society_, Series B, 23(1):223–229 (which includes examples) ... or see some of the recent work by Wilhelm and Manjunath such as: http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-1/RJournal_2010-1_Wilhelm+Manjunath.pdf